# Why $\int_x^1\int_x^1\frac{ds\;dt}{1-st}=2\int_x^1\log(1+t)\frac{dt}{t}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

How can one derive the above equality?

Oh, there's a condition on $x$, which is $0<x<1$

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: A change of variables should suffice. Note that

$$\log (1+t)=\int\limits_0^t \frac{dx}{1+x}$$

Comment: Can you write it in more detail? I can't quite see changing variables will produce constant 2 on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: This identity is on page 273 of the book "The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class" authored by J.Michael Steele. But it doesn't explain why.

Comment: I think the first step should be $\int_x^1\int_x^1\frac{dsdt}{1-st}=2\int_x^1(\int_t^1\frac{ds}{1-st})dt$. Actually, I think I already know how to derive this identity. Anyway, it's a good exercise, so I'll leave other people write the whole solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is extended version of the caozhu's comment.

Note that integration goes over square $[x,1]\times[x,1]$ and function $f(s,t)=\frac{1}{1-st}$ is symmetric, i.e. $f(s,t)=f(t,s)$ hence
$$
\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_t^1f(s,t)dsdt=
\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_s^1f(s,t)dtds
$$
So,
$$
\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_x^1f(s,t)dsdt=
\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_t^1f(s,t)dtds+
\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_s^1f(s,t)dsdt=
2\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_t^1f(s,t)dtds
$$
Then we get iterated integral
$$
\int\limits_x^1\int\limits_x^1f(s,t)dsdt=
2\int\limits_x^1dt\int\limits_t^1\frac{ds}{1-st}=
2\int\limits_x^1dt\left(-\frac{\log(1-st)}{t}\right)_{s=t}^{s=1}=
2\int\limits_x^1\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}dt
$$